# Weird String.replace() function return

Tags: java

Okay so I have this function that's suppose to return a string with some characters replaced

```
String x = "DannyKrosis@Gmail.com";

private String Algorithm() {

    for (int a = 0; a < x.length(); a++)
    {

        switch (x.charAt(a)) { // Goes over each character until the '@' character is found
        case '@':
            x = x.replace(x.charAt(a), ' '); // Replaces the '@' character with blank space

            for (int b = a; b >= 0; b--) // From where the '@' was, replaces all characters before it
            {
                x = x.replace(x.charAt(b), ' ');
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    return x.replaceAll("\\s+", ""); // Removes all spaces to make string clean :)
}
```

When this function returns the string I get

```
"Gml.cm"
```

When I want it to be

```
"Gmail.com"
```

So I tried this function hoping to get my desired result

```
String x = "DannyKrosis@Gmail.com";

private String Algorithm() {

    boolean y = false;  

    for (int a = 0; a < x.length(); a++)
    {
        switch (x.charAt(a)) {

        case '@':
            x = x.replace(x.charAt(a), ' '); // Removes '@' symbol from string

            x = x.replaceAll("\\s+", ""); // Removes all excess spaces

            y = true; // Stops for loop

            break;

        default:
            x = x.replace(x.charAt(a), ' '); // Replaces all other character before the '@' character with spaces
            break;
        }

        if (y) // Stops for loop
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return x;
    }
```

And to my surprise I get the same result of

```
"Gml.cm"
```

Does any know what's wrong with my loop or switch statement? I can't seem to find the issue causing this.

Comment: You appear to want to use `x.substring(x.indexOf('@'))`, or something like, instead of this whole method.

Comment: @AndyTurner, or `x.substring(x.indexOf('@') + 1)`, cause the OP does not want to have the `@` in `Gmail.com`.

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz sure. I'm really just pointing out that wheels are being reinvented here, and they're square in the new design.

Comment: you could also use x.split("@"). The first element of the array will contain the text before the @

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to simply want to get the domain from an email address. That's easy: assuming you've got an `@` in the string, just return the substring following this:

```
return x.substring(x.indexOf('@') + 1);
```

(Thanks to [GrzegorzGórkiewicz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4280359/grzegorz-g%c3%b3rkiewicz) for pointing out my out-by-one error in the comment)

---

But, the reason for your unexpected output in your code above is that you're misunderstanding what `String.replace(char, char)` does: it replaces *all* occurrences of the first parameter with the second parameter. This is perhaps confusing, since there is a `replaceAll` method too; that does the same, but uses regular expressions for the matching and replacement.

The best way to do it similar to your code is to use a `StringBuilder`: this allows you to mutate the single character at your current index:

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(x);
for (int a = 0; a < x.length(); a++) {
  char c = s.charAt(a);
  s.setCharAt(a, ' ');
  if (c == '@') {
    // Replace the spaces, etc, like above.
    x = s.toString().replaceAll("\\s+", "");
    return x;
  }
}
x = s.toString();
return x;
```

Note that a two-case switch, where one of the cases is `default`, is much more easily written as a conditional: the `y` variable presumably only exists to help you break the loop; you could just use `break` directly if you're not in a `switch` (and anyway you could use a labelled break, or a `return`).

Comment: what would you prefer, regex approach(as it's done with simple lookbehind regex) or substring approach for getting domain from email address?

Comment: Substring, as suggested here. It's miles simpler.

Comment: Thank you SO much, you're a genius, I didn't know that StringBuilder had so many useful tools

Answer (score 1):

`x.replace(x.charAt(a), ' ')` replaces the characters which it found. Like it founds a and i in your loop and replace a and i from `gmail` too.

In your string `DannyKrosis@Gmail.com`, there is a and i it founds before @ and so `x.replace(x.charAt(a), ' ')` replace `a` and `i` from `gmail`.

`replace` method replaces all character which it matches with given character rather than replacing in given index only

If you want to get value after @, you can simply use lookbehind regex :

```
(?<=@).*
```

Comment: To clarify: `replace()` replaces every letter *in the whole string* that exists in the word `DannyKrosis`. Every `d`, `a`, `n`, `y`, `k`, `r`, `o`, `s` and `i` gets replaced, so that only `g`, `m`, `l`, `.`, `c`, and `m` remains.

Answer (score 0):

Since two other posts already addressed the problem with your code and suggested solution to achieve your goal, I just want to share an alternative in my answer.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String x = "DannyKrosis@Gmail.com";
    boolean y = false;
    for (int a = 0; a < x.length(); a++) {
        switch (x.charAt(a)) {
            case '@':
                x = replaceCharAt(x, a, ' ');
                x = x.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                y = true; // Stops for loop
                break;
            default:
                x = replaceCharAt(x, a, ' ');
                break;
        }
        if (y) {
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(x); // prints "Gmail.com"
}

public static String replaceCharAt(String s, int pos, char c) {
    return s.substring(0, pos) + c + s.substring(pos + 1);
}
```